# PostgreSQL reset a value to default daily?

Tags: postgresql

I have my own database server that is on 24/7.
What I want is to have a column that will reset its value to default daily.
How do I do this?

For example,

Table(Int ColmA, ColmB)

ColmA has a default value of 5 and it will get decrement by some application.
How do i make it to reset the value back to 5 daily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [crontab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). Run in terminal:

```
crontab -e
```

(on some systems you need to switch to `postgres` user beforehand: `sudo su postgres && crontab -e`) and type in editor something like:

```
0 0 * * * psql <your_database_name> -c "UPDATE YourTable SET ColmA = 5"
```

Quit the editor. From now on every midnight UPDATE query will be executed.